# MomentJs Format One Day Behind

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have seen a question that is similar to mine ([Moment.js sets dates to 1 day behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473932/moment-js-sets-dates-to-1-day-behind)) but I can't seem to apply it.

Essentially, my date gets parsed like this:

```
var date = moment("2019-05-27T00:00:00Z"); // date is the 27th
```

When I format it to get the day, expecting the 27th, I instead receive the 26th!

```
date.format("DD")
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to correct it?

http://jsfiddle.net/rmdxj26e/

[image]

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan because your timezone is different :)

Comment: Please try removing the "Z".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use [moment.utc()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/), the [Moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) says:

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
>
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use
>   moment.utc() instead of moment().
>
> This brings us to an interesting feature of Moment.js. UTC mode.
>
> While in UTC mode, all display methods will display in UTC time
>   instead of local time.
>
> ```
> moment().format();     // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00  
> moment.utc().format(); // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00
> ```

**jsFiddle Output**:

[image]

**Live example:**

```js
var date = moment.utc("2019-05-27T00:00:00Z");
$('#date').append($('<p>').html(date.format("DD")));
$('#date').append($('<p>').html(date.local().format("DD")));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Fraction - that's what I was looking for.  I didn't fancy arbitrarily slicing off the "Z."

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the format of the parsed date. The `Z` letter means it is a "Zulu time" (UTC). I don't know what is your timezone, but the date is converted to your timezone.

You can parse local time format (without `Z`) and it should display properly.

So the full code with explanation:

```
var date = moment("2019-05-27T00:00:00"); // date is the 27th in local time
$('#date').append($('<p>').html(date.utc().format("DD"))); // can display 26th or 27th depends on local timezone on the PC
$('#date').append($('<p>').html(date.local().format("DD"))); // is still local so it will be 27th
```