# toISOString() is subtracting day from value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, toisostring

I have this date format:
Tue Oct 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)

And when I do :

myValue.toISOString();

that's what I get

**2020-10-19T23:00:00.000Z**

It's subtracting a day.

How can I solve this without changing date format?

Comment: It's not subtracting a day. Midnight GMT+1 *is* 11pm GMT.

Comment: timezones.jpg same issue as there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473932/moment-js-sets-dates-to-1-day-behind/50474386#50474386

Answer (score 1):

> The toISOString() method returns a string in simplified extended ISO format (ISO 8601), which is always 24 or 27 characters long (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ or ±YYYYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ, respectively). The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

As your current timezone (Central European Standard Time) is GMT+1 Thats why you had the day-1 time. which is infact just UTC current time. Your region is one hour ahead of the UTC. If you check at different time of a day this will not be a difference of one day but just one hour.

Comment: And what should I do about that?

Comment: You should normalize your time when showing it to user to user timezone. ISO time will be UTC time. and that is the time you should be saving. And then show time according to the user timezone.

Comment: @nour-may still programming? ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
let date = new Date('Tue Oct 20 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100');
console.log('date: ' + JSON.stringify(date));
let result = date.toLocaleDateString("fr-CA",{year:"numeric", month:"2-digit", day:"2-digit"});
console.log('result: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
```

date: "2020-10-19T23:00:00.000Z"

result: "2020-10-20"

Comment: It's working but I have to send the date to my back-end in iso format